# 'Received Memory Warning" while saving frames to images in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, uiimage

Below code is to save each frame of a movie to Photo Album in iPad device... After about 60 frames saved into Image.. it gives me 'Received Memory Warning.." error and my app crashes eventually.. what goes wrong here? Am I missing something..?  I use iOS 7...

```
  -(UIImage *) getImageFromGLBuffer : GLuint frameBuffer : (CGCize) screenSize
{
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    int width = screenSize.width;
    int height = screenSize.height;

    NSInteger iDataLength =  width * height * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc( iDataLength );
    glReadPixels(0,  0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
    // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(iDataLength);

    for(int y = 0; y <height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width * 4; x++)
        {
            buffer2[(int)((height - 1 - y) * width * 4 + x)] = buffer[(int)(y * 4 * width + x)];
        }
    }

    // Release the first buffer
    free((void*)buffer);

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, iDataLength, releaseBufferData);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    // then make the UIImage from that
    UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; //[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];

    NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);     // get png representation
    UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return pngImage;
}

// callback for CGDataProviderCreateWithData
void releaseBufferData(void *info, const void *data, size_t dataSize)
{
    NSLog(@"releaseBufferData\n");
    // free the buffer
    free((void*)data);
}

- (void)saveImageToPhotoAlbum : GLuint frameBuffer : (CGCize) screenSize
{
    if( iqFrameBuffer != nil )
    {
        UIImage* image = [self getImageFromGLBuffer:frameBuffer : screenSize];

        if( image != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save to Photo Album due to invalid image..");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Frame buffer is invalid. Couldn't save to image..");
    }
}

// callback for UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Image has been saved to Photo Album successfully..\n");
 //   [image release];   // release image
    image = nil;
}
```

Comment: You're dispatching to a concurrent queue - suggest you try using a serial one. Also, add log msgs when you queue an image (like its index) and when it finishes writing, to insure you are not queuing way more images than get written (and that be the source of your memory problems). All you memory management appears correct to me (on a cursory read).

Comment: Did not help that... even before creating the UIImage it gives "Memory" warning.. Am I missing something in OpenGL part?

Comment: Or is there any limitation(memory wise) for an iOS app to save photos into Photo Album?

Comment: Why don't you either reword your question (to include more of OpenGL), or post another question more specific to it. Also, log when buffer2 is created and keep the log in when its released. Look at the logs when you get the memory warning - are you creating a slew of buffers before any get released. I did something similar to this on the Mac years ago, but I stored the frames in the file system. To avoid overwhelming things, I did a simple diff between each frame, then stored a difference file (but I had more cores to work with obviously).

Comment: I am not sure why I received -2 votes on this!!!

Comment: Excuse me? I show you at a total of 0... You should read one of my replies - I spent like 30 min to screen capture some keychain screens to try and help someone. Not to solve it, but to provide more info. I got down voted and went bezerk and left a really caustic comment, which itself got up voted!